# How to make TinyMCE (Rich Text Editor) the default C5 editor

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

One of my sites uses the TinyMCE editor, and another site does not.  Having been away from C5 for a bit, I can't figure out where/how to make the TinyMCE editor the default Rich Text Editor.  I've looked in Google, SO and found nothing.  Help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Are you sure using version 5.7? Because this version uses Redactor as editor

Comment: What's happening is when I go to edit a block, it shows the HTML source; NOT what I want... how do I fix this?

Comment: It's a content block? or a html block?

Comment: RATS!  I think it's a HTML block!  I've been away from it for some time now, and have forgotten most of the details... please rewrite your last comment as an answer so I can give you the points!  And thanks for responding... I really appreciate it!  SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're using a **HTML-Block** not a **Content-Block**.

As you may see [in the docs](http://documentation.concrete5.org/editors/in-page-editing/block-areas/add-block) there are different type of blocks.

The **HTML-Block** is as its name suggests, for pure HTML and JavaScript.
The **Content-Block** is attached to the [Redactor Rich text editor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/).

Comment: Thanks again... I really, really appreciate it!